# Diferenças de diretivas no Angular

Tags: angular

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença das declarações de diretivas.

Por exemplo:

```
ng-for=""
*ngFor="" (o que é esse asterisco?)
ngFor=""
[ngStyle]
```

Já vi e utilizei dessas formas, mas nao encontrei as diferenças.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ng-for` era usado no AngularJS ou seja versões 1.X

O ngFor sem o asterisco está errado e gera um erro.

O jeito correto de fazer nas versões a partir do angular 2.x é com `*ngFor`, isto por que o `*ngFor` assim como o `*ngIf` e outras são chamadas de [diretivas estruturais](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). Estas diretivas manipulam o dom diretamente por isso o asterisco é uma mensagem para o angular avaliar elas primeiro. Vale lembrar que você não pode usar duas no mesmo elemento.

De acordo com a documentação da tag:

```
<div *ngIf="hero" class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

vira

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

ou seja o Angular cria esta tag `ng-template` ao redor do seu div nesse caso e avalia o if antes de decidir se adiciona ao dom o div ou não. O `ng-template` é uma tag fantasma que não existe no dom(não atrapalha o css) realmente e faz alguma lógica.

E o [ngStyle] e outro tópico, basicamente você pode linkar uma propriedade de uma tag html a uma variável no seu TypeScript. Por Exemplo:
no seu html

```
<a [href]="minhaUrl">link</a>
```

no seu component

```
export class AppComponent {
  minhaUrl='https://google.com'
}
```

e equivalente a

```
 <a href="https://google.com">link</a>
```

Com  a vantagem que você pode mudar o valor nesse caso de minhaUrl e a propriedade mudaria de acordo.

Repare que em um caso você passa o nome de uma variável que contem o valor e no outro você passa o valor diretamente.

Comment: Excelente Eduardo! Era isso mesmo que procurava. Uma duvida: existe ngStyle, sem os colchetes? Ou até mesmo *ngStyle?

Comment: @MarcoGarcia não, o que vc pode fazer é [ngStyle]="'valor'" repare nas aspas simples entre as aspas duplas.