# Tem alguma diferença entre ng-if e *ngIf

Tags: angular

Qual a diferença entre **ng-if e *ngIf** em Angular 5? As duas implementações funcionam normalmente no Angular 5?

Comment: Com *ngif você pode ter um else, com ng-if não, mas pode ter outras coisas que eu não sei de diferente entre esses dois por isso vou comentar e não responder.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277782/57801

Comment: `ngIf=""` é diretiva, `*ngIf=""` diretiva estrutural; é necessário usar o `*` quando usado em template uma marcação que indica que `ngIf=""` ira resultar na alteração da estrutura `html`, tem uma resposta completa no stack em ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271949/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-if-in-angular2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O **ng-if** era usado no AngularJS

O ***ngIf** é usado no Angular (versão 2.x ou superior)