# UIkit com interpolação em Angular 7

Tags: angular

Estou utilizando UIkit com Angular 7, e no momento estou tentando setar o valor do '**title**' do tooltip vindo do componente Angular, algo como:

```
<progress class="uk-progress" max="{{rodadas.length}}" value="{{rodadaVigente}}" uk-tooltip="title: {{nomeRodadaVigente}}; pos: bottom"></progress>
```

Mais recebo uma exceção! Alguém sabe como contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No angular para setar uma propriedade de um html ou componente com base numa propriedade do seu ts basta usar o colchetes invés da propriedade normal. [Diferenças de diretivas no Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277782/diferen%C3%A7as-de-diretivas-no-angular/282619#282619)

```
<progress class="uk-progress" [max]="rodadas.length" [value]="rodadaVigente"
 [uk-tooltip]="nomeRodadaVigente"></progress>
```

Comment: Fiz as seguintes tentativas: [uk-tooltip]="title: {{rodadaVigente}}; pos: bottom" / [uk-tooltip]="title: rodadaVigente; pos: bottom", sem sucesso! Recebo a seguinte exceção: (compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'uk-tooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'progress'. ("remove">...)

Comment: esse componente progress vc que fez? Parece que ele não achou o componente uk tooltip e ele não vai entender essa interpolação vc tem que criar uma propriedade correta no seu typescript e passar pra ele.