# Existe diferença de performance usando ngIf diretamente em um componente

Tags: javascript, angular, aplicação-web, front-end

Olá, Alguém poderia me informar se existe diferença de performance nos trechos de código abaixo, e se existe, qual seria o mais performático? Obrigado!!

```js
<div *ngIf="false">
    <componente></componente>
</div>

<componente *ngIf="false"></componente>
```

Comment: Você chegou a testar se o `ngIf` funciona dentro de `<componente></componente>`?

Comment: Na realidade ambas as formas funcionam... o que gostaria de saber é se o <componente> chega a ser instanciado no DOM e depois retirado do DOM, ou se nem no DOM ele entra. Outro detalhe... no exemplo fica mais claro se for usado o false... por que a dúvida é no carregamento do componente. Não sei se ficou claro.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas tem a mesma performance o ngIf é uma diretiva estrutural com isso ele gera um ng-template em volta do elemento que você coloca ele e manipula o dom de acordo. Sendo assim em nenhum caso ele instancia o componente se o ngIf for false. No entanto tem difernça entre a semantica e de estilo visto que o div tem um display block e o componente não necessariamente.

```
<componente *ngIf="hero" class="name">{{hero.name}}</componente>
```

vira

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <componente class="name">{{hero.name}}</componente >
</ng-template>
```

mais informações: [Diferenças de diretivas no Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277782/diferen%C3%A7as-de-diretivas-no-angular/282619#282619)