# SRC de um áudio como variável

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Bom dia, estou tendo um problema para adicionar a src de um audio passando por um modal.
A página funciona da seguinte forma:
1) O usuário clica em um botão que abre um modal com uma lista de áudios.
2) Dentro do modal há uma array de audios com os seguintes parametros:

```
{
        id: 1,
        nome: 'Música 1!',
        music: '/assets/musics/bensound-littleidea.mp3',
        image: '/assets/logo.png'
    },
```

3) Após selecionar o áudio dentro do modal, ele deve apresentar o áudio na página inicial

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true">
       <audio preload="auto" controls #audio>
         <source src="{{music}}"> //caminho do audio aqui
          <p>console.log(data.music)</p>
         </audio>
     </div>
```

Dei um console.log(responseModal.data.music); pra ver se pelo menos ele pega o caminho, e está funcionando, ele me retorna o caminho do áudio.

Preciso por esse caminho na src={{}} mas não está funcionando.

Array das musicas:

```
public musicaList: any[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nome: 'Música 1!',
        music: '/assets/musics/bensound-littleidea.mp3',
        image: '/assets/logo.png'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nome: 'Música 2!',
        music: '/assets/musics/bensound-summer.mp3',
        image: '/assets/logo.png'
    }

];
```

Função pra pegar o caminho:

```
pegaMusica(music : any) {
    let parametroDeResposta = {music};
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss(parametroDeResposta);

}
```

Função da página principal após dar dismiss no modal:

```
 modal.onDidDismiss().then((responseModal: OverlayEventDetail) =>{
      if(responseModal !== null){
        console.log(responseModal.data.music);

      }
    })
```

Comment: Dentro do modal, em qual variável você tem acesso as informações da música(objeto)?

Comment: dentro de uma array de musicas: public musicaList: any [] =

Comment: Adicionei a função e pegar o caminho e a string

Comment: Faz assim: <source [src]"music">

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277782/diferen%c3%a7as-de-diretivas-no-angular/282619#282619

Comment: Console me retorna: GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Arrumei adicionando a resposta do modal à uma variável e dado id (audio-player) à div do áudio.

```
 modal.onDidDismiss().then((responseModal: OverlayEventDetail) =>{
      if(responseModal !== null){
        console.log(responseModal.data.music);
        this.music = responseModal.data.music;
          document.getElementById('audio-player').load();
      }
```